# Adding Search Functionality to ListView with inputSearch

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm new in programming. This is my list view fragment and I  want to
        add search for easier to find any item in list.

When I used 'EditText inputSearch;' I get question to 'import com.example.planer.R;' so I imported that, then when I have to use
'inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);' I got error on R.id.inputSearch, I post auto suggestion in code.

Any Sollution?

Also I apologize for the poor knowledge of English.

Here is my List View Class:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_list_view, container, false);
    sveAktivnosti = NavigationDrawerExampleActivity.sveAktivnosti;
    ListViewAdapter arrayAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(sveAktivnosti, getActivity());

    ListView a =  (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    a.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);  
    //inputSearch cannot be resolved or is not a field
    //2 quick fixes available
    //Create field 'inputSearch in type 'id'
    //Create constant 'inputSearch in type 'id'
    return view;        
}

public ArrayList<Activity> getSveAktivnosti() {
    return sveAktivnosti;
}

private void setSveAktivnosti(ArrayList<Activity> sveAktivnosti) {
    this.sveAktivnosti = NavigationDrawerExampleActivity.sveAktivnosti;

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are trying to link an unknown object `inputSearch` to an EditText with id `inputSearch` that is located on your `layout/activity_list_view.xml` file, located in the `res/` directory of your project.

You can resolve this issue by creating an EditText object first.

Change the line with the problem to:

```
//Declare variable inputSearch of type EditText
EditText inputSearch;  
//Link the inputSearch variable with the EditText with id inputSearch that should be present in layout/activity_list_view.xml
inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
```

Comment: I post my xml files , scroll down.

Comment: I just update my xml file with <EditText android:id="@+id/inputSearch">
and other thinks, so I will try to fix 

inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

findViewById request a method..

Answer (score 0):

You are associating (inflating) the layout `R.layout.activity_list_view` to your view. Are you sure "R.id.listView1" is defined there? Please **post your xml** file as well. Anyway, you should look for the EditText inside THAT view, so try to change

```
inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
```

To:

```
EditText inputSearch = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
```

So, you're getting "inputSearch cannot be resolved or is not a field" because you have to declare it (`//inputSearch cannot be resolved or is not a field`). Anyway, if you're not doing anything dynamic with it (say, change text size) you can delete that line as the view is being inserted by .inflate() call

Answer (score 0):

Here is list_item.xml

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ListName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ListDate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />
```

Here is activity_list_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have failed to define the EditText inputSearch in your XML thus why the code can't find it. You would need to have the EditText inputSearch defined in the XML as well. So your activty_list_view.xml should look more like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<EditText
android:id="@+id/inputSearch"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="EditText" />

<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/listView1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

</ListView>
```

Comment: I just update my xml file with <EditText android:id="@+id/inputSearch"> and other thinks, so I will try to fix inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch); findViewById request a method.